# How can I install Memcached php extention on windows 10 (xampp)

Tags: php

How can I install Memcached php extention on windows 10 (xamp). 
I need memcacheD extention not memcache to use [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) php class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer from github](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/374#issuecomment-352733819)

> A Windows binary is not provided for this extension. You would need to
>   compile your own. Here's a starting point for installing a PECL
>   extension on Windows:
>
> https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php
>
> This extension relies on the libmemcached library, here's starting
>   points for compiling that as well:
>
> https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tangent-trunk/libmemcached/1.0/view/head:/README.win32
>   https://github.com/yshurik/libmemcached-win